# How to manage references on Access 2010 and Access 2016 in the same database

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I have an Access Database working with Access 2010 and 2016. 
So, If is firstly opened with 2016, when a user open it with 2010, a reference error trying to access to Excel library (Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library) occurs. To solve it I need to change manually the reference to 14.0 one in the reference menu.

I'm trying to do this programatically in VBA, checking the version of Access, if version is 2010 (14.0) I need to delete Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library and add 14.0 instead. When is 2016 I think I dont need to do anything.

trying two options:

1. With Precompiling Code and directives:

> ```
> #Const ver = Application.version
> #If ver = "14.0" Then
>     Call References.AddFromFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe")
> #End If
> #If ver = "16.0" Then
>     'Call References.AddFromFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe")
> #End If
> ```

My problem here, checking documentation, is that i'm not totally sure if I can check access version in precompiling time.

2. In my initial form open method

> ```
> If Dir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe") <> "" And Not refExists("excel") Then
>     Access.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe")
> End If
> If Dir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe") <> "" And Not refExists("excel") Then
>     'Access.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe")
> End If
> If Dir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe") = "" And Dir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe") = "" Then
>     MsgBox ("ERROR: Excel not found")                                  
> End If
>
> Private Function refExists(naam As String)
> Dim ref As Reference
> refExists = False
> For Each ref In References
>     If ref.Name = naam Then
>         refExists = True
>     End If
> Next
> End Function
> ```

In this time, my initial form have many internal references and some of them takes Excel library. When I try to do this, the error occurs after executing the code.

Does anyone knows what can I do to solve this problem? I hope my code help you understand the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than having a reference set to the relevant Excel library and using Early binding (i.e. `Dim objXL As New Excel.Application`), remove the reference to Excel and use Late binding (`Dim objXL As Object: Set objXL=CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

Comment: _I'm not totally sure if I can check access version in precompiling time._ ... so why not check it out? That will provide the definitive answer.